# If a JDBC Connection object's scope is local, does it need to be explicitly closed? (MySQL database used)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a method that is of type `Connection`.  It returns the `Connection` value once it connects to the database.  Here is the code:

```
public Connection establishConnection()  
{

    Connection conn = null;
    try 
    {
        this.readLogin();  // prompts user to input for user, pass and host variables using Scanner class
        this.createDatabaseIfNeeded();  // creates chessleaguedb if not found     
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection
                    ("jdbc:mysql://"+host+":3306/chessleaguedb", user, pass);
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to chessleaguedb");

    } 
    catch (SQLException z ) 
    {
        // logic
    }   
    return conn;
}
```

I then create an instance of this method's class in my menu class; call the above method and pass its return value to a Connection object in the menu class (I do this just to keep things clean, and hopefully adhere to good OO design principles) :

```
DatabaseConnection startConnection = new DatabaseConnection();  // class the above method is located in
Connection connect = startConnection.establishConnection();
```

My question is this: because an active connection is being opened in the above method, do I need to explicitly close it in the method?  Or because the `Connection` object in that method is local and will not exist after the method ends, is that necessary?  I can't close it, because calling the relevant close method after `return conn;` gives me an unreachable statement error in NetBeans.  EDIT* I cannot use Pooling as not Java EE, and cannot use open source software to handle it as work must be my own as this is university work (2nd year).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to write & handle the `closeConnection()` in your `DatabaseConnection class`, otherwise it will create a connection leak in the application. Very soon, your application will run out of connections.

You need to ensure that the below `closeConnection()` being called in the `finally` block of the same method from where you are calling `establishConnection()`, otherwise resource (`connection`) will escape (causing leaks).

```
public void closeConnection(Connection conn) {
   try {
        conn.close();
   } catch(SQLException sqlexe) {
     // Connection closing failed
    //Log exception
  }
}
```

**But, it is NOT a best practice to handle the connections explicitly like this, rather try to use a connection pooling mechanism.**

You can look at [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/connpoca.htm) for connection pooling.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: The important bit here is that nothing magic when variables drop out of scope. They might eventually be GCed, but that's it; locks aren't released, connections aren't returned to a pool, Closeables are closed, etc.

Comment: @javaguy appreciate the code.  If I were to call "conn.closeConnection()" after the return statement in the method, it gives me an error of unreachable statement.  Maybe it's bad design on my part in the first place, but how should I close it in a method that returns the Connection value?

Comment: We need to ensure that the closeConnection() is being called from finally block, in which ever method establishConnection() is called.

Comment: @javaguy done, and now sorted. RE: pooling.  should have mentioned in question. it's second year undergrad work and not using Java EE, and not allowed to use open source software to hande pooling as work must be my own.

Answer (score 2):

Connection implements AutoCloseable.

I would use try-with-resources paradigm as it would auto close the resource and there is no need to explicitly close the resource.

```
try(Connection connect = startConnection.establishConnection()){

}catch(SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return("failed");
 }
```

More information on try-with-resources with JDBC objects can be found [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/using_try_with_resources_with)

General information on try-with-resources can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Very interesting,  "Connection implements AutoCloseable"

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly close the connection.Better create a Finally block and close the connection by conn.close();

Answer (score 1):

You have to close the connection object , else it would create connectionLeaks which might potentially crash your DB server.

The scope being local limits the usage of the connection object and does not reduce the lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

You should close the connection, however strictly not needed, beacuse before or later it will be closed by the jvm. But you don't know when, so you could come to connection leaks or memory problems.
However you should review your architecture. Connecting to db each time would be very slow, error prone and resource consuming. Try to work with connection pools or at least reuse your open connection in a safe way

Comment: It could also be that some other parts of the driver (or connection pool) hold on to the connection if not explicitly closed, therefor never freeing the connection.